# PowerShell Script call out from another PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to call a PowerShell script from another PowerShell script. The script I'm trying to call is in a subfolder named "Release" of the current directory.

I tried the following command but get an 'file not found' error from the PowerShell console.

```
."..\Release\out-datatable.ps1"
```

Comment: You'll need to provide a little more detail about the error condition than "is going wrong"

Comment: i edited my post so can delete your downvote, it's a serious question

Comment: How *exactly* is it "going wrong"? Do you get errors? If so, what do they say? If you don't get an error: what *do* you get? And how does that differ from what you expect?

Comment: Please post the *exact* error message.

Comment: @Arturka1 I didn't downvote - but the quality of your question (serious or not) justifies a downvote none the less

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen you are right but i have edited the question hopeful it is more usefull now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by simply change to the subdirectory.
I wrote the following command to my script

```
cd Release

. .\out-datatable.ps1
```