# Run PowerShell script from another script, passing string variables

Tags: powershell

I got two Powershell script.
The first, script1.ps1, got some Global string variable.

The second, script2.ps1, must do some operation with values of the string variables, then close without passing any data to the first.

Here pieces of code.

**script1.ps1**

```
#[ENG] Global $language contains the language name: EN-US for american english, EN-GB for english of Great Britain, for example.
$global:language = $culture.Name

#[ENG] Global $workPath variable contains the path of the folder with the original files.
$global:workPath = "D:\Documents\Downloads\Emule-Incoming\osis"

#[ENG] Global $scriptPath variable contains the path of the script(s) files.
$local:temp = Split-Path $PSCommandPath
$global:scriptPath = "$temp"
$temp = ""

##########
# mods.d #
##########

#[ENG] Global $modBip variable contains the path of destination of CONF files for BPBiblePortable.
$global:modBip = "D:\Documents\Downloads\Emule-Incoming\BPBiblePortable\App\BPBible\resources\mods.d\"

#[ENG] Global $modXip contains the path of destination of CONF files for xiphos.
$global:modXip = "C:\Users\Emanuele\AppData\Roaming\Sword\mods.d\"

#[ENG] Global $modGit variable contains the path of destination of CONF files in GitHub Desktop to upload and synchronize in GitHub.
$global:modGit = "D:\Documents\GitHub\EmanueleTinari\mods.d\"

$scriptPath = $scriptPath + "\" + 'cei1974.ps1 $language $workPath $scriptPath $modBiP $modXip $modGit'
Invoke-Expression & $scriptPath
```

**script2.ps1**

```
#[ENG] Retrieve Global variable's values.
Param ([string]$language, [string]$workPath, [string]$scriptPath, [string]$modBiP, [string]$modXip, [string]$modGit)

Write-Host $language
Write-Host $workPath
Write-Host $scriptPath
Write-Host $modBiP
Write-Host $modXip
Write-Host $modGit
```

What I try:

```
$scriptPath = $scriptPath + "\" + 'cei1974.ps1 -$language $language -$workPath $workPath -$scriptPath $scriptPath -$modBiP $modBiP -$modXip $modXip -$modGit $modGit'
Invoke-Expression & $scriptPath
```

I add -$[string name] : nothing to do.

```
$scriptPath = $scriptPath + "\" + 'cei1974.ps1 -$language $language -$workPath $workPath -$scriptPath $scriptPath -$modBiP $modBiP -$modXip $modXip -$modGit $modGit'
Invoke-Expression $scriptPath
```

Without & near $scriptPath : nothing to do.

I, first write this question, examined and tryed answers in this posts:

[Run a PowerShell script from another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549516/run-a-powershell-script-from-another-one)

[PowerShell Script call out from another PowerShell Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29917753/powershell-script-call-out-from-another-powershell-script)

[Invoke powershell script from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32257257/invoke-powershell-script-from-another)

[Passing varibale into powershell script that is being executed from another script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37159861/passing-varibale-into-powershell-script-that-is-being-executed-from-another-scri)

How can I achieve to pass strings between this two script? Tnx in advance.

Comment: Did you took a look at dot sourcing? With that you can access the variables from the first script.

Answer (score 0):

Swap-out the last 2 lines in your `script1.ps1` script with this:

```
. $scriptPath\script2.ps1 -language $language -workPath $workPath -scriptPath $scriptPath -modBiP $modBiP -modXip $modXip -modGit $modGit
```

Some notes:

- Do not use `Invoke-Expression` followed by the ampersand (&) call operator, as that is unnecessary.
- You have all the information necessary to call script2.ps1 directly, rather than build-up a string and rely on expression evaluation.
- When specifying script command-line parameters by name, simply use a hyphen (-) followed by the parameter name.  For example, `-language $language`.
- I believe you want to use dot-sourcing (.) to call your script2.ps1.  You could also defer to using the ampersand (&) call operator.  Invoke-Command and Invoke-Expression could be used, but can also be exploited if not handled correctly.

For more information, see `Get-Help about_Operators` and `Get-Help about_Scripts` and `Get-Help about_Parameters`